# How to know what encryption is used by WebRTC connections?

Tags: javascript, encryption, webrtc

I am using WebRTC's data channels (obtained with `RTCPeerConnection.createDataChannel()`) and I would like to know what cipher and key size is actually used by the underlying transport. Unless I missed it in the [WebRTC API](http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/webrtc.html), there is no function to get that information. Is it possible to get it? if so, how?

Comment: I don't expect that the DTLS information is made available, TLS information in general is not available as JS level. I *guess* the establishment of the media streams is up to the browser itself; you don't want to perform DTLS in JavaScript, that's for sure. That said, at least an information channel *should* have been made present to ask for the specific TLS cipher suite. For just debugging, use [WireShark](http://wiki.wireshark.org/DTLS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Chromium/Chrome this has been implemented through the stats API and should be available in one of the next releases:
https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=3976